# How can I detect that SessionContext.setRollbackOnly has been called in a method of an EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions

A backing bean (JSF) calls a method of an EJB in which a transaction is started. The transactions are managed by the container in the EJB. The method of the EJB can invalidate the transaction by calling `setRollbackOnly`. How can I detect it in the backing bean?

It would be simple if the EJB method threw a system exception in the EJB method instead of calling `setRollbackOnly`. What's the advantage of `setRollbackOnly` over throwing an exception?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject the EJB context directly in the JSF managed bean.

Just expose current transaction state through a public method.

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext context;

    // related getter / setter
    ...

   public boolean hasRolledBack() {
        return context.getRollbackOnly()
   }
}
```

You can also throw yourself an exception if the transaction is marked as rolled back.

Regarding your 2nd question the transaction has been rolled back by an exception thrown across the boundaries of a transnational method, but it has been caught somewhere later in the execution flow. (better throw a RuntimeException on error you cannot deal with so no one will catch it)

Comment: Thanks Gab, but I don't understand how it solves my problem. How the backing bean which has called the method of the EJB knows whether the transaction has been rolled back or not? Could you give me a sketchy code of the method of the backing bean to detect the rollback?

Comment: If I throw a system exception in addition to setRollbackOnly, I can detect the rollback but, then, I don't see the utility of setRollbackOnly because only throwing the system exception is enough to trigger an automatic rollback.
So I wonder when it is better to call setRollbackOnly than to throw a system exception.

Comment: 1 : just inject the EJB in the backing bean and call hasRolledBack() on it
2 : there were an exception thrown somewhere otherwise the transaction would not be rolled back. Just find the place where it is caught

Comment: Thanks for your patience Gab. 1. I don't think that hasRolledBack() will return true *after* the end of the transaction (according to the javadoc, "current transaction"). 2. The transaction has perhaps been rolled back by setRollbackOnly without any exception thrown (because a management rule is not fulfilled).

Comment: ah indeed if the transaction boundaries are on the EJB method, you will have to maintain the state somewhere (e.g. thread local variable) for further access. Throwing an exception looks like much more elegant Imho.

Comment: So, if am not mistaken, we agree: setRollbackOnly is not very useful in this case. Thanks to you, perhaps I understand now when setRollbackOnly could be useful: when another EJB than the EJB which called setRollbackOnly is called within the same transaction and this other EJB need to know if the transaction has been rolled backed. setRolledbackOnly is not useful if the transaction is within a single EJB (in this case, it is better to throw a system exception in order to warn the object which called the EJB). Am I right?